# Generalizing adding nested lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given 3 nested vectors:

```
 >>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> b
[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
>>> c
[[100, 200, 300], [400, 500, 600], [700, 800, 900]]
```

I can add these vectors together with a map/sum/zip comprehension like so:

```
>>> [map(sum,zip(i,j,k)) for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c)]
[[111, 222, 333], [444, 555, 666], [777, 888, 999]]
```

I've manually expanded this from adding two lists together, but is there a pythonic way to generalize this to handle an arbitrary number of lists?

(Python 2.7 without using external libraries preferred)

Comment: Without external libraries you mean? `itertools` may be a useful import

Comment: Additionally - can it be generalized to arbitrary levels of nesting? (not my actual problem but just occurred to me as related)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks - that's more what I meant. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @paulw1128 you are sliding towards recursion with your thoughts. Be careful son. xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a general approach:

```
from itertools import izip
def multiple_sum(*args):
    return [map(sum, izip(*items)) for items in izip(*args)]
```

Demo:

```
In [13]: multiple_sum(a, b, c)
Out[13]: [[111, 222, 333], [444, 555, 666], [777, 888, 999]]
```

Note that since in Python 2.7 `zip` returns a list it's better off using it when you only want to iterate over the results, and instead use `itertools.izip` that returns an iterator.

Here is another way using `itertools.starmap()` which is faster than the previouse approach:

```
def multiple_sum(*args):
    return [map(sum, lst) for lst in starmap(zip, zip(*args))]
```

Benchmark:

```
In [32]: %timeit [map(sum, izip(*items)) for items in izip(a, b, c)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.93 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit [map(sum, lst) for lst in starmap(zip, zip(a, b , c))]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.01 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
lists = [a,b,c]
[map(sum,zip(*zipped_lists)) for zipped_lists in zip(*lists)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of lists (`[a,b,c]`), you can do the following:

```
>>> lists = [a,b,c]
>>> [map(sum, zip(*l)) for l in zip(*lists)]
[[111, 222, 333], [444, 555, 666], [777, 888, 999]]
```